# Label file in tensorflow object detection training

Tags: tensorflow, classification, object-detection

I want to create my own `.tfrecord` files using `tensorflow object detection API` and use them for training. The record will be a subset of original dataset so the model will detect only specific categories.
The thing I don`t understand  and can`t find any information about is, **how are id`s assigned to labels in label_map.pbtxt during trainin**g.

What I do...

Step 1:
assign label_id during creation of the tfrecord file, where I put my own ids:

```
'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(category_ids)
'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(category_names)
```

Step 2:
create labels file with e.g. two categories:

```
item { name: "apple"  id: 53  display_name: "apple" }
item { name: "broccoli"  id: 56  display_name: "broccoli" }
```

Step 3:
Train the model

After training, there are some objects detected, but with **N/A label**. **When I set the id`s starting from 1 then it shows correct labels**.

My questions are:

1. Why it did not map correctly to label with custom id?
2. Can the second id have other value than 2? I'm sure I saw skipped ids in labels file for coco dataset.
3. How to set the id to have custom value, if possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my label map. After Googling a bit, I found your question here and also this excerpt from the TensorFlow Object Detection [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md):

> Each dataset is required to have a label map associated with it. This label map defines a mapping from string class names to integer class Ids. The label map should be a `StringIntLabelMap` text protobuf. Sample label maps can be found in object_detection/data. **Label maps should always start from id 1**.

I also checked the source code for [label_map_util.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py) and found this comment:

> We only allow class into the list if its id-label_id_offset is
> between 0 (inclusive) and `max_num_classes` (exclusive).
> If there are several items mapping to the same id in the label map,
> we will only keep the first one in the categories list

So in your example, which only has two classes, valid ID's are 1 and 2. Any higher value will be ignored.

Comment: What about taking a subset. If you have images belonging only to id 2. do you need to rewrite the label map?

Comment: @JürgenK. I believe so

Comment: @JürgenK.  not needed. The model will not be affected. Would never prime up to output 1.